# Combining conditional queries isn't working properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm needing to use the parse.com method `orQueryWithSubquerries:` to create a combined conditional query.

Here is my code for it:

```
PFQuery *testQuery = [PFUser query];
[testQuery whereKey:@"displayName notEqualTo:@"Bob"];

PFQuery *testQuery2 = [PFUser query];
[testQuery whereKey:@"username" notEqualTo:@"frank"];

PFQuery *orQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[testQuery, testQuery2]];
[orQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        PFUser *user = [users firstObject];
    }
}];
```

The code runs fine, but it returns all of my user objects, including the ones that should be filtered out from the 2 queries. Am I using this method wrong, or is there a certain way that I need to use it?

Edit:

I have also attempted to use this method exactly [like how this parse.com example does](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-compound/iOS), but it still doesn't work properly.

```
PFQuery *testQuery = [PFUser query];
[testQuery whereKey:@"numberOfPhotos" greaterThan:@(3)];

PFQuery *testQuery2 = [PFUser query];
[testQuery whereKey:@"numberOfPhotos" lessThan:@(1)];

PFQuery *orQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[testQuery, testQuery2]];
[orQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // users still contains every user in the app even though it shouldn't according to the parse example
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do a compound query, just query regularly:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"displayName" notEqualTo:@"Bob"];
[userQuery whereKey:@"username" notEqualTo:@"frank"];
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        PFUser *user = [users firstObject];
    }
}];
```

You're confusing the use of a compound query, as you have it currently,

TestQuery = All users whose display isn't bob.  (includes users whose username is frank)

TestQuery2 = All users whose username isn't frank.  (includes users whose display name is Bob)

When you combine them, you get all of the users, your compound is contradictory.

Basically, all of the users left out in query1 are included in query2. And, all the users left out in query2 are included in query1.  When you combine these queries, they fill in the missing space and you get all users.

#### Update

If you're trying to do hasPrefix, it seems like it should work fine:

```
NSString * prefixToSearch = ...;

PFQuery * displayNameQuery = [PFUser query];
[displayNameQuery whereKey:@"displayName" hasPrefix:prefixToSearch];

PFQuery * usernameQuery = [PFUser query];
[usernameQuery whereKey:@"username" hasPrefix:prefixToSearch];

PFQuery * compoundQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[displayNameQuery, usernameQuery]];
[orQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Found %i users", users.count);
    }
}];
```

#### Update 2 - Let's Test

```
PFQuery *testQuery = [PFUser query];
[testQuery whereKey:@"numberOfPhotos" greaterThan:@(3)];

PFQuery *testQuery2 = [PFUser query];
[testQuery whereKey:@"numberOfPhotos" lessThan:@(1)];

PFQuery *orQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[testQuery, testQuery2]];
[orQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // users still contains every user in the app even though it shouldn't according to the parse example

        for (PFUser * user in users) {
            int numberOfPhotos = [user[@"numberOfPhotos"] intValue];
            if (1 <= numberOfPhotos && numberOfPhotos <= 3) {
                NSLog(@"Query is failing");
            }
        }

    }
}];
```

#### Update 3 - Predicates!

Via our conversation, we got it working with this:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyOne BEGINSWITH 'z' OR keyTwo BEGINSWITH 'a'"]; 
PFQuery * userQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User" predicate:predicate]; 
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { 
    NSLog(@"Found objects: %@", objects); 
}];
```

Comment: My original objective is to use the string matching method `whereKey:hasPrefix:`. I am needing to perform a search for users that match the entered username or display name. That is why I am using the 'or' method. I need results for either or.

Comment: If you need results for either / or, I suggest using a predicate.  If you'd rather do a compound query, you'll have to repeat yourself a touch more.  For example, in query 2, you often need to add some parameters from query 1 to properly filter out results.  The problem here is that you're saying if field 1 != A, or field2 != A.  This will only filter out objects whose field 1 AND field 2 != A.  So if someone's displayname is Bob, AND their username is Frank, your query will filter them out.

Comment: Can you show the version you're using with prefixes?  I might be able to clean it up for you.

Comment: I updated to show prefix stuff.  If you're querying in that way, I think what you have should work.  You're on the right track, it just looks like your test is a bit off.

Comment: I did try it exactly as you have written, but that doesn't work either. I also added an edit to my original post, which shows that it's not working even though I tried an identical example to how parse shows its application.

Comment: Ok, I see it.  You're definitely implementing it correctly, have you triple checked your data table to make sure that some users have number of photos 1, 2, 3.  With your current query, those users shouldn't be included. I'll update in a sec w/ a way to test it.

Comment: I am positive that it should filter users properly based off of the data I have. Also I just tested it with a query that isn't of type user and it worked fine... I did a nearly identical orQuery search with the results I'm looking for. Is it possible that querying users doesn't work properly?

Comment: Maybe there's an ACL problem, have you added constraints?  I threw up a test case, but it sounds like you've done all that stuff already.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52051/discussion-between-jonathan-and-logan)

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this once again I ended up changed my solution to being regex based rather than predicate. For my purposes that means I don't need to create an additional lowercase display name property since Parse regex allows for case-insensitive options. Also I can more easily change the parameters of the search with higher levels of flexibility.

My code now looks like this:

```
// Uses regex to remove white space at the beginning and end of search text
NSString *modifiedSearchText = [Utility stringTrimmedForLeadingAndTrailingWhiteSpacesFromString:self.searchText];

PFQuery *userUsernameQuery = [PFUser query];
// the @"i" modifier is stated in the parse documentation and means case-insensitive
[userUsernameQuery whereKey:@"username" matchesRegex:modifiedSearchText modifiers:@"i"];

PFQuery *userDisplaynameQuery = [PFUser query];
[userDisplaynameQuery whereKey:@"displayName" matchesRegex:modifiedSearchText modifiers:@"i"];

PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[userUsernameQuery, userDisplaynameQuery]];
[userQuery orderByAscending:@"username"];

return userQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8.3, xcode 6.3.1

```
query.whereKey("name", matchesRegex:searchBar.text, modifiers:"i")
```

searches upper or lowercase words